# How to implement non-distributed locks which expire?

Tags: concurrency, redis, locking, memcached, concurrent-programming

Meaning, they don't have to be distributed. I'm thinking about using `memcached` or `redis` for that. Probably the latter one. What I'm concerned about is "we've got to free some memory, so we'll delete this key/value before it expired" thing. But I'm open to other suggestions as well.

Comment: You can set expiration on keys, but also using Redis as a LRU cache as a whole if that is your question.

Comment: I didn't get the point. With `memcached` I don't see any way to ensure that it doesn't delete the key, because it's out of memory. `redis` should be able to guarantee this. And the question is which exactly way do I take, `redis`, `memcached`, anything else? And how do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr** Use [ready-made solution](http://redis.io/topics/distlock), suggested by developers.

So, I decided not to use `memcached` for the purpose. Since it's a caching server. I don't see a way to ensure that it doesn't delete my keys because it's out of memory. With, `redis` that's not an issue as long as `maxmemory-policy = noeviction`.

[There](http://redis.io/commands/set) [are](https://engineering.gosquared.com/distributed-locks-using-redis) 3 [links](http://redis.io/commands/setnx) I want to share with you. They are basically 3 ways, that I now know, to solve the issue. As long as you have `redis >= 2.6.0` that is.

#### redis >= 2.6.12

If you've got `redis >= 2.6.12`, you're lucky and can simply use [`setnx`](http://redis.io/commands/set) command with its new options `ex` and `nx`:

```php
$redis->set($name, <whatever>, array('nx', 'ex' => $ttl));
```

But we can't just delete the lock in the end, if we are to allow for critical section taking longer then we expected (`>= ttl`). Consider the following situation:

```
C1 acquires the lock
lock expires
C2 acquires the lock
C1 deletes C2's lock
```

For that not to happen we are going to store current timestamp as a value of the lock. Then, knowing that Lua scripts are atomic (see [Atomicity of scripts](http://redis.io/commands/eval)):

```php
$redis->eval('
    if redis.call("get", KEYS[1]) == KEYS[2] then
        redis.call("del", KEYS[1])
    end
', array($name, $now));
```

However, is it possible for two clients to have equal `now` values? For that all the above actions should happen within one second and `ttl` must be equal to `0`.

Resulting code:

```php
function get_redis() {
    static $redis;
    if ( ! $redis) {
        $redis = new Redis;
        $redis->connect('127.0.0.1');
    }
    return $redis;
}

function acquire_lock($name, $ttl) {
    if ( ! $ttl)
        return FALSE;
    $redis = get_redis();
    $now = time();
    $r = $redis->set($name, $now, array('nx', 'ex' => $ttl));
    if ( ! $r)
        return FALSE;
    $lock = new RedisLock($redis, $name, $now);
    register_shutdown_function(function() use ($lock) {
        $r = $lock->release();
        # if ( ! $r) {
            # Here we can log the fact that lock has expired too early
        # }
    });
    return $lock;
}

class RedisLock {
    var $redis;
    var $name;
    var $now;
    var $released;

    function __construct($redis, $name, $now) {
        $this->redis = get_redis();
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->now = $now;
    }

    function release() {
        if ($this->released)
            return TRUE;
        $r = $this->redis->eval('
            if redis.call("get", KEYS[1]) == KEYS[2] then
                redis.call("del", KEYS[1])
                return 1
            else
                return 0
            end
        ', array($this->name, $this->now));
        if ($r)
            $this->released = TRUE;
        return $r;
    }
}

$l1 = acquire_lock('l1', 4);
var_dump($l1 ? date('H:i:s', $l1->expires_at) : FALSE);

sleep(2);

$l2 = acquire_lock('l1', 4);
var_dump($l2 ? date('H:i:s', $l2->expires_at) : FALSE);   # FALSE

sleep(4);

$l3 = acquire_lock('l1', 4);
var_dump($l3 ? date('H:i:s', $l3->expires_at) : FALSE);
```

#### expire

The other solution I found [here](https://engineering.gosquared.com/distributed-locks-using-redis). You simply make the value expire with `expire` command:

```php
$redis->eval('
    local r = redis.call("setnx", ARGV[1], ARGV[2])
    if r == 1 then
        redis.call("expire", ARGV[1], ARGV[3])
    end
', array($name, $now, $ttl));
```

So, only `acquire_lock` function changes:

```php
function acquire_lock($name, $ttl) {
    if ( ! $ttl)
        return FALSE;
    $redis = get_redis();
    $now = time();
    $r = $redis->eval('
        local r = redis.call("setnx", ARGV[1], ARGV[2])
        if r == 1 then
            redis.call("expire", ARGV[1], ARGV[3])
        end
        return r
    ', array($name, $now, $ttl));
    if ( ! $r)
        return FALSE;
    $lock = new RedisLock($redis, $name, $now);
    register_shutdown_function(function() use ($lock) {
        $r = $lock->release();
        # if ( ! $r) {
            # Here we can log that lock as expired too early
        # }
    });
    return $lock;
}
```

#### getset

And the last one is described again in [documentation](http://redis.io/commands/setnx). Marked with "left for historical reasons" note.

This time we store timestamp of the moment when the lock is to expire. We store it with [`setnx`](http://redis.io/commands/getset) command. If it succeeds, we've acquired the lock. Otherwise, either someone else's holding the lock, or the lock has expired. Be it the latter, we use [`getset`](http://redis.io/commands/getset) to set new value and if the old value hasn't changed, we've acquired the lock:

```php
$r = $redis->setnx($name, $expires_at);
if ( ! $r) {
    $cur_expires_at = $redis->get($name);
    if ($cur_expires_at > time())
        return FALSE;
    $cur_expires_at_2 = $redis->getset($name, $expires_at);
    if ($cur_expires_at_2 != $cur_expires_at) 
        return FALSE;
}
```

What makes me uncomfortable here is that we seem to have changed someone else's `expires_at` value, don't we?

On a side note, you can check which `redis` is it that you're using this way:

```php
function get_redis_version() {
    static $redis_version;
    if ( ! $redis_version) {
        $redis = get_redis();
        $info = $redis->info();
        $redis_version = $info['redis_version'];
    }
    return $redis_version;
}

if (version_compare(get_redis_version(), '2.6.12') >= 0) {
    ...
}
```

Some debugging functions:

```php
function redis_var_dump($keys) {
    foreach (get_redis()->keys($keys) as $key) {
        $ttl = get_redis()->ttl($key);
        printf("%s: %s%s%s", $key, get_redis()->get($key),
            $ttl >= 0 ? sprintf(" (ttl: %s)", $ttl) : '',
            nl());
    }
}

function nl() {
    return PHP_SAPI == 'cli' ? "\n" : '<br>';
}
```